# How to create 404 error page in php

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I am using php. I have been to create a custom error page using .htaccess file , the problem is i was not able to upload it on the server using ftp, even after trying in so many ways, so Is there any solution for this, so that I can create a custom error page without the ".htaccess" file.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean, "create a custom error page"? If you want to provide one to replace the default Apache 404 page, you will need to tell Apache to use YOUR file instead of serving up the default response. The standard method for that is to use a .htaccess, and have

```
ErrorDocument 404  /uri/leading/to/your/script.php
```

relevant [docs here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#errordocument).

Simply uploading a random file will not magically make Apache use it when a 404 occurs - that's where the ErrorDocument directive comes in. As well, .htaccess does not "create" an error page. It simply tells Apache where to look when one does occur.

Comment: Yes, Its absolutely correct, M y problem is different , I am not able upload ".htaccess" file on server, So i am asking you is there any other ways so that i can create 404 page without the ".htaccess: file

Comment: Nope. either you need a .htaccess file to provide the local override to enable the ErrorDocument config, or you have to modify the httpd.conf. There's no other way. However, why are you not able to create a .htaccess? The server doesn't allow it? Produces a 500 internal error? Or just can't create a file named ".htaccess" before uploading it?

Comment: 1) server is not allowing to upload ".htacces" file giving me "critical file transfer error" 2) Cant able to create a ".htacces" file also on server, however i can create in my local machine 3) not allowing me to rename any "htaccess" to ".htaccess" its giving me "550 Permission denied on server.  You are restricted to your account." error

Comment: I think the problem is with the server, i checked here http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/smallbusiness/webhosting/gftp/gftp-13.html